# TCL Code to Convert file

Tags: tcl

I have a huge file which has different fields like below:

```
ip server-ip-address = 20.29.77.10/22
tcp either-port = 80
```

I need to write script to convert these fields into below format.What will be the most efficient way to do this?

```
remote-ip 20.29.77.10/22
remote-port eq 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the most efficient way would be to call out to sed:

```
exec sed -i {
    s/^ip server-ip-address =/remote-ip/
    s/^tcp either-port =/remote-port eq/
} $filename
```

Comment: Executing an external program is not actually running Tcl, so this seems like an invalid answer.

Comment: Tcl is a general purpose scripting language. All such languages can call out to external programs. If those programs are faster and/or more efficient, then why not use that capability? Tcl is really my first love and it's never broken my heart. But I also love sed and awk and perl. You have to pick the best tool for the job.

Comment: Because Tcl includes both the regexp and regsub command which cover this sort of functionality. Yes, one could exec sed, but why would that make any sense when the functionality is already built directly into Tcl. Also, the script is significantly more portable if exec is not used. It is not an issue of could but one of should.

Comment: And there are also the questions of: how much developer time needs to be invested; are we reinventing an already well-tested wheel; how fast will it run; how much memory will it consume; etc etc

Comment: Glenn, the question is not "SED Code to Convert file". I am at a loss to understand what is going to convince you.

Comment: Why do you think I need convincing? I've given my answer, you've given yours -- its up the the voters and the OP now. Don't forget that the OP is not the only person who will benefit from advice given on this page, so it's good to have multiple approaches to this problem. Also, in my experience here, it's frequent that those asking questions are aided by "left field" answers that they haven't thought of or even known about.

Answer (score 1):

Glenn Jackman's solution could be implemented like this on a system that lacks `sed` (untested code):

```
package require fileutil

proc conv data {
    regsub -all -line {^ip server-ip-address =} $data remote-ip data
    regsub -all -line {^tcp either-port =} $data {remote-port eq}
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace $filename conv
```

I suppose `sed` is quicker where available.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method would be to write a single regexp command that matches the entire line and extracts the input as a series of tokens. You have to know what all the tokens are up front, so they can be included in the regexp command, but then it is basically just 1 command to do the whole parse operation. Another method would be to use the split command on the whole line and pass " " as the 3rd argument and then run through each string token with the foreach command.

Comment: I updated the formatting of the question. You might want to revisit your answer.